# How to upload PDF File as Form-data in Karate Framework for API Automation?

Tags: api, postman, karate

I'm trying to post a pdf file and model data using a POST request.
The values are as follows,
model= {"param1":true, "param2": false}
File = "filename.pdf"
These values are shown as "form-data" in Postman. I'm trying to pass these values using Karate Framework from Eclipse. In header there are Authorization = 'Bearer' and Content-type= 'application/json' already present.

Comment: sorry, it is near impossible to remotely troubleshoot multi-part requests. work with your server-side team if needed